# list property inside of a struct

Tags: c#

How do I write a property for a list inside of a struct?

my code:

```
public struct Config
{
    List<int> ipAddress = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: Highlight, right-click, refactor, encapsulate field.

Comment: So what problem are you facing?

Comment: @jeffamaphone that's visual studio specific, author might be using another ide.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: How do I write set and get property for a List.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a struct? In most cases you probably want a class. See this explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: @AndrewKennan - precisely, i think a lot of folks choose `struct` because they **assume** it's more performant without really considering the full implications...  The MSDN guidance is pretty good on when to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is to create an auto-property (which will default to `null` for reference types and *cannot* be initialized) you can do as @scartag suggests.

```
public struct Config
{
    // will default to null
    List<int> ipAddress {get; set;}
}
```

However, if you're trying to do what's in your code and initialize it to an actual reference, you will run into issues because you can't initialize fields in a `struct`.  They can only have their defaults.  To make matters even worse, you can't override a default constructor to do this for you.

Generally speaking, `struct` tends to be best for small, preferably immutable types.  Is there a reason you don't want to just use `class` for this?

Now, if you *did* want to create a `struct` with an "initialized" field, you can fool it with some lazy logic:

```
public struct Config
{
    private List<int> _ipAddress;
    private bool _isAssigned;

    public List<int> 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (!_isAssigned)
                _ipAddress = new List<int>;
            return _ipAddress; 
        }
        set
        {
            _ipAddress = value;
            _isAssigned = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But really, at this rate it's better to use a `class` since you *can* initialize fields, or override the default constructor:

```
public class Config
{
    public List<int> ipAddress {get; set;}

    public Config()
    {
        ipAddress = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

And again, as Andrew mentioned in the comments, I strongly suggest looking at [MSDN guidance on choosing between `struct` and `class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, I went with a class instead.

Answer (score 2):

See below.

```
public struct Config
{
    List<int> ipAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you prefer not to use the automatic get/set

```
public List<int> ipAddress 
{
    get
    {               
        return ipAddress?? new List<int>();
    }       
    set 
    {
        ipAddress = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note though this won't automatically assign to a new instance, it will be `null` (and you can't override default constructor in `struct`)